# Учет по характеристикам bitrix и 1С

Tags: битрикс, 1с, интернет-магазин

Есть сайт на CMS битрикс (http://www.zelenyjostrov.ru/). На нем необходимо реализовать "Учет по хар-кам".

**Например, сейчас на сайте есть карточка товара:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Эта карточка ( как и любые другие ) имеет 1 размер и 1 цвет, соответственно у подобного товара с другим цветом (или размером) есть отдельная карточка. (представляете какой ад в 1С образовался, с учетом того, что товаров около 15к :P)

**Задача заключается в том, чтобы у посетителя был выбор когда он заходит на карточку, выбрать цвет, размер и в зависимости от выбранного цвета или размера менялась цена.**

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чего начать и куда смотреть?

Comment: Копать надо в сторону торговых предложений со стороны битрикса
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42&CHAPTER_ID=06772&LESSON_PATH=3912.4771.6772
Как их реализовать - отлично описано в курсе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно использовать торговые предложения - SKU, но если у вас в 1с каждый товар тоже не разделён на характеристики (как вы и написали), то стандартная выгрузка в битрикс тоже не сможет выгрузить Вам в битрикс товары с торговыми предложениями.

Я так вижу, что вам не обойтись без допиливания выгрузки. Вам нужно или:

- писать обработчик, который будет стараться товары объединять и создавать из них один товар с характеристиками.
- или создать свойство дополнительное, в которое например записывать общий для одинаковых товаров артикул, и допиливать вывод товаров в клиентском интерфейсе, где по этому новому свойству собирать схожие товары и показывать.

Вообщем так и так программировать надо будет.